# How do I ensure google sheets saves csv files properly when string fields contain a variable amount of spaces?

Tags: csv, google-sheets, separator

I've run into the following issue:
I have a table like this

```
Username                Bool
FrankWebster            TRUE
LillyYoung              TRUE
Chris Pratt             FALSE
Phillip Jack Jacobs     FALSE
```

Sadly this results in additional, unwanted columns as if the spaces in the strings are being used as column separators. Shown here:

[image]

What I need is for the contents of each column to stay in their respective column.
However, adding underscores for spaces or marking the Usernames as strings by adding quotation marks at the front and end of the names is not an option.

Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

Comment: Your analysis is incorrect. **Sheets** is saving the file properly. Whatever program you are using to Open the file is using `<space>` as the delimiter. Change that program to use `<comma>` as the delimiter.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output